# Undefined return in Javascript in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Why do I get an undefined result from this code?

**index.html**

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="emp_name" placeholder="Employee Name" >
  <p id="en"></p>
</div>
    <script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#submit_password" ).submit(function() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ret){
        $( "#thank_you" ).show();
        $("#submit_password").slideUp();
        console.log(ret);
      }).sendPassword(this); 
      reloadSite();
    });
    getEmployeeName();
  }); 

function getEmployeeName(){
    alert(google.script.run.getEmployeeName());
    document.getElementById('emp_name').value = google.script.run.getEmployeeName();
    var name = google.script.run.getEmployeeName();
    document.getElementById("en").innerHTML = name;
  }
<script>
```

**code.gs**

```
function getEmployeeName(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N-AeSs-vOa2nLPWx9gNBkeVkSq7Vp7D-0DWpXH1nh5o/edit#gid=0')
  .getSheets()[0];
  var value = ss.getRange(5,2,1,1).getValues();
  var name = value[0][0];
  Logger.log(name);  
  return name;
}
```

But in my Logger I get the expected result. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The code is run asynchronously and probably hasn't finished executing and the result is still undefined.

try adding to the HTML

```
function suc(x) {
  return x;
}
```

and then

```
document.getElementById('emp_name').value = 
    google.script
          .run
          .withSuccessHandler(suc)
          .getEmployeeName();
```